# Combine rows into one using multiple columns in Python

Tags: python

*Solved - Issue with the original dataset I was using*

I have a large csv file of prescription data, The first column contains the Year issued, the second column contains the name of the chemical substance, third column the practice, 4 col number of items.

```
Year       Chemical substance     Practice   Items     
2019       Bisoprolol             Practice A 10         
2019       Bisoprolol             Practice B 12
2020       Bisoprolol             Practice A 13
2020       Bisoprolol             Practice B 15
2019       Omeprazole             Practice A 12
2019       Omeprazole             Practice B 12
2020       Omeprazole             Practice A 13
2020       Omeprazole             Practice B 15
2019       Tolteridone            Practice A 13
2019       Tolteridone            Practice B 14
2020       Tolteridone            Practice A 12
2020       Tolteridone            Practice B 12
```

I want to combine the data for the practice and year so that it will give me a total issued per practice, similar to this output,

```
Chemical substance    Practice    Items
Bisoprolol            Practice A  23
Bisoprolol            Practice B  27
```

I have tried groupby,

`merged_df = prescribingdata_df.groupby(['Chemical substance', 'Practice']).agg('sum')`

but I just get the data output the same as the original. Is there a way to combine both the rows based on 2 columns? So that the data for the year and the practice are shown?

Comment: Please close as irreproducible, since you confirmed it is

Comment: Apologies I am not sure how to close a question?

Comment: James that's ok, other people will vote-to-close as irreproducible/not MCVE and it will get closed.

Answer (score 0):

try this brother, you forgot the `''`

```
merged_df = prescribingdata_df.groupby(['Chemical substance', 'Practice']).agg('sum')
```

Comment: Sorry my bad! It was a typo in the question. My code in python has it in ' '

Comment: I have just replicated the data in a separate notebook making the small sample data and it works fine...Must be an issue with the original data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There appeared to be an error in the data as when I ran this again in another notebook it worked fine